# Kendo Grid - ASP MVC is not displaying the drop down list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

I'm developing a project with ASP MVC 5, Kendo UI, and some layers, but I'm struggling with how to display the **drop-down list** inside of an **editable Grid**, I followed this example:

[Grid Editing / custom editor](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-custom)

However, I'm having serious issues because the drop-down list never *appears*, it's displaying two text boxes.

[image: example]

Also, if I run the **Foreign Key column** example:

[Grid / ForeignKey column](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/foreignkeycolumn)

I have a different result with a numeric up-down:

[image: Example 2]

Besides, I tested this example from StackOverflow and the result is either two textboxes or the numeric up-down (it depends if I bound the column or I use the foreign key column):

[dropdownlist in kendo grid not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365961/dropdownlist-in-kendo-grid-not-working)

This is my code, in the **Business Layer**, I have these classes in order to return the Categories from the database:

```
using Test.DB.Operations;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test.Business
{
    public class Category
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class CategoryData
    {
        public static List<Category> GetCategories()
        {
            var catData = DatabaseService.GetEntities<DB.Category>().ToList();

            return (from cData in catData select new Category() { ID = cData.ID, Name = cData.Name }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Later, in my **MVC Layer**, the **Controller** populates the view with some methods like these ones:

```
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using Test.Business;
using Test.Classes;
using Test.MVC.Classes;
using Test.MVC.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Test.MVC.Controllers
{
    public class OrganizationDetailsController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string ID)
        {
            PopulateCategories();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ID))
            {
                var model = new OrganizationsModel();
                try
                {
                    model.hasError = false;
                    model.messageBox = null;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    model.hasError = true;
                    model.messageBox = new Tuple<string, string>("Error", "Please report it to the team");
                }
                return View(model);
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }    

        public ActionResult OrganizationDetails_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string ID)
        {
            try
            {
                var data = OrganizationDetailsData.GetOrganizationDetails(ID);
                DataSourceResult result = data.ToDataSourceResult(request);
                return Json(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult OrganizationDetails_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]<OrganizationDetails> oDetails)
        {
            return null;
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult OrganizationDetails_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<OrganizationDetails> oDetails)
        {
            return null;
        }

        private void PopulateCategories()
        {
            var dataContext = CategoryData.GetCategories();

            ViewData["categories"] = dataContext;
            ViewData["defaultCategory"] = dataContext[0];
        }
    }
}
```

The **Model** looks like this:

```
using Test.Business;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Test.MVC.Models
{
    public class OrganizationsModel
    {
        public Tuple<string, string> messageBox;
        public bool hasError;
    }
}
```

Finally, in the **View**, I have this code for the Kendo Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Test.Business.OrganizationDetails>()
    .Name("gridDetails")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(b => b.Name);
        columns.Bound(b => b.NumberOfEmployees);
        //columns.ForeignKey(p => p.CategoryID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["categories"], "ID", "Name").Title("Categories").EditorTemplateName("dropdownTemplate");
        columns.Bound(b => b.Category).ClientTemplate("#=Category.Name#");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Telephone);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Address);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolBar =>
    {
        toolBar.Create();
        toolBar.Save();
    })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.ID);
            model.Field(p => p.ID).Editable(false);
            model.Field(p => p.Category).DefaultValue(ViewData["defaultCategory"] as Test.Business.Category);
        })
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Action("OrganizationDetails_Read", "OrganizationDetails").Data("LoadParams"))
        .Create(create => create.Action("OrganizationDetails_Create", "Grid"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Organization_Update", "Grid"))
    )
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
)

<input type="hidden" id="orgID" value="1" />

<script id="dropdownTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
        .Name("myDropDown")
        .DataValueField("ID")
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["categories"])
    )
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function error_handler(e) {
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function () {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
            });
            alert(message);
        }
    }

    function LoadParams() {
        var id = $("#orgID").val();
        return { ID: id }
    }
</script>
```

However, it's never working as it should be. Does anyone have experience this issue? And how did you manage it? Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the ForeignKey() implementation:

you have to put the "dropdownTemplate" in a cshtml file in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates.  You cannot use a x-kendo-template because you are not using javascript initialization...you are using the razor helpers.  What is likely happening to your is that you are specifying an non-existent EditorTemplate(no cshtml in Shared/EditorTemplates) so it just breaks.

Or, you can leave off the EditorTemplateName() altogether and Kendo will automatically use the EditorTemplate in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/GridForeignKey.cshtml.

For the "ClientTemplate" implementation:

If you take a look at the full source code for the "Grid Editing / custom editor" example(in the examples that get installed with Kendo MVC), the EditorTemplate is specified using a UIHint on the model.
i.e. (using your classnames)

```
public class OrganizationDetails
{
    ...

   [UIHint("ClientCategory")]
    public CategoryViewModel Category {get; set;}
}
```

Then there must be a ClientCategory.cshtml file in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates that contains the razor for your editor implementation.

In the Kendo examples, ClientCategory.cshtml contains:

```
@model Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.CategoryViewModel

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
    .DataValueField("CategoryID")
    .DataTextField("CategoryName")
    .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["categories"])
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't know about the UIHint, it's not in its web page at all maybe they should provide it or explain it somehow. I'm pretty sure it's related to the ProductViewModel that is not part of the example, I couldn't find it before. Thanks for the clarification!